# Как подружить Wordpress с PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, phonegap, windowsphone

Привет всем! Есть проект стильный мобильный шаблон на wordpress добавить в него вкладки описание бренда, фотки, видео, магазин. и подружить всё это добро с phonegap.

результатом работы получается готовый сайт + моб. приложения (ios android winphone). с админки вордпресса удобно будет управлять всем приложением, добавлять товар в магазин например или делать уведомления об акциях.

Но как это сделать весь инет перерыл никак не могу разобраться. с сайтом вордпресс всё понятно, а вот как с phonegap подружить тут затык.

Парни если у кого какие идеи буду рад любой))) если будут какие либо ссылки на ресурсы тоже готов изучить желательно на русском)) если такие есть. а после реализации обещаю не обидеть

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте приложение из одного `webview`, который будет открывать Ваш мобильный сайт.

Comment: вЕРНО СКАЗАНО!!!